# onResponse() not called in REST call for Android using retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

So, I'm trying to connect to Scryfall's API and do an autocomplete call. I've been able to use their other call properly but this one I think where I'm having issue.

Here is the call:  https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete?q=fire
q is the query and it will return a list of up to 20 items that could be auto-completed with the word 'fire'.

```
{
    "object":"catalog",
    "total_values":20,
    "data": [
        "Fire // Ice","Fire Imp","Firefly","Fire Whip","Fire Ants","Firebolt","Fireball","Fire Drake","Fire Snake","Firespout","Firestorm","Fireblast","Fire-Field Ogre","Fire Urchin","Fire Bowman","Fire Dragon","Fire at Will","Fire Ambush","Firemaw Kavu","Fire Juggler"
    ]
}
```

I am using retrofit2 for android.

Here is some of my code.

*This is my interface for the endpoints*

```
public interface ScryfallEndPoints {
//https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=
@GET("cards/named")
Call<Card> getCard(
        @Query(value=("fuzzy")) String name);

//https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete?q=
@GET("cards/autocomplete")
Call<Card> getCardAutoComplete(
        @Query(value=("q")) String name);
 }
```

*This is a method I use in my activity to perform the call.*

```
private void loadCardList()
{
    final ScryfallEndPoints apiService =
            APIClient.getClient().create(ScryfallEndPoints.class);

    Call<Map<String, String>> call = apiService.getCardAutoComplete(str);


    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, String>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, String>> call, Response<Map<String, String>> response)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionResults.this, "onResponse()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, String>> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionResults.this, "onFailure()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
        }
    });

    //tv.setText(str);

}
```

Here is a method that is part of my model class.

```
 @SerializedName("data")
private Map<String, String> cardList;

public Map<String, String> getCardList() {return cardList;}
```

So, I feel like there is definitely something maybe wrong in the way I am trying to access he data in my model class and maybe with the way I have it set up in my interface. When I make the call, it doesn't fail so I don't have error logs to show, i just know that it is going to the onFailure() method and I'm not sure why. I mostly need to figure this out then I can work on getting the list to populate. Also, if there is a way that I can see more of what is going on with the calls that I am making, that would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: what you need to do is to understand "how to create POJO from JSON" and how to receive a JSON response from the API while using Retrofit.  "http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/" will help you

Comment: @rahat I have a pojo class and have used that site. I only attached a part of the relevant code from that class, my model class. I pasted what I got from that site already.

Comment: but you are trying to receive in the map `Callback<Map<String, String>>`,

Comment: it fails because for the key `data` the value is not a string but one array

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("cards/autocomplete")
Call<Card> getCardAutoComplete(
        @Query(value=("q")) String name);
 }
```

Then the calling part

```
//Call<Map<String, String>> call = apiService.getCardAutoComplete(str);

//It returns Call of Card type, hence it will be as follows

Call<Card> call = apiService.getCardAutoComplete(str);


    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<Card>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Card> call, Response<Card> response)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionResults.this, "onResponse()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Card> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SuggestionResults.this, "onFailure()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've done some editing to my code. It looks like how you have it now and it still isn't working. I have also changed my data method to Map<String, String> and it's not working either. Maybe i'm overlooking something small.

Comment: did you try with this code? what happened?

Comment: nothing. I added an image to my question. Hopefully it is visible.

Comment: you  just edited my answer, edit your question.